# Can somebody explain to me what this is telling me to do?

Tags: java, algorithm

> Design a linear algorithm that finds a contiguous subsequence of at
>   most M in a sequence of N long integers that has the highest sum among
>   all such subsequences. Implement your algorithm, and confirm that the
>   order of growth of its running time is linear.

I've read it a couple of times, but I'm having a difficult time understanding what it wants me to do.

Comment: What is 'it'? Your homework assignment? If so, better to ask your TA than us.

Comment: http://codercareer.blogspot.com/2012/02/no-33-maximums-in-sliding-windows.html

Comment: @TonyRad - Not quite. OP is given a _maximum_ windows size. That link assumes a given window size. The optimal size may be less than the maximum.

Comment: You could use the same algorithm as the blogspot link by @TonyRad, just modify it to use composite set of queues with different window sizes. But then again, I can't think of a case where the answer subsequence can have less than M integers.. unless zeros should be ignored?

Comment: Wait, there can be. If N - 1 integers are negative, and 1 integer is positive, the answer subsequence would be of count 1, containing only the positive integer. Right? But it sounds quite a special case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that you have 10 integers in a line. You can pick any 1,2 or 3 of them in sequence and add them up. You need to find out which ones you would pick so that the sum is maximum. In this case M=3, N=10.
Your algorithm must run in linear time.

Comment: Also it needs to run in linear time, so when you add more integers to the line, the number of comparisons should increase proportionally.

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer.

Comment: This is now a nice answer to OP's question: "What does this mean?"

Comment: @AlexGitelman please check the answer I posted if it provides a good example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it means like this (following counts of Alex's answer):

```
N = 10
144  23  89   21  145  2   11  9  1   69

M = 3 (this is max)

take 1 number
highest is 145

take 2 numbers consequtive
highest is 144 + 23 = 167

take 3 numbers consequtive
highest is 144 + 23 + 89 = 256

Therefore answer = 144, 23, 89
```

Negative or zero included:

```
N = 10
0  -23  -89   21  -145  -2   11  -1  1   69

M = 3 (this is max)

take 1 number
highest is 69

take 2 numbers consequtive
highest is 1 + 69 = 70

take 3 numbers consequtive
highest is -1 + 1 + 69 = 69

Therefore answer = 1, 69
```

Please comment if I'm right or wrong.

<strike>I cannot find a situation where the count of numbers in the subsequence can be less than M. No matter how I think about it, it has to be M.</strike>`*` Only the window need not always include the highest among the N integers.

`*` Ok I found one case where the count is less than M. See the second code block above.

Comment: its correct. an important detail is that they didn't say the integers had to be positive.

Comment: Oh yes, maybe I should try negatives and zeros mixed in.